# How to get a property of a tuple with a string?

Tags: swift, tuples

I'm starting in Swift, I come from JavaScript, and some things are a bit confusing for me, is there something similar to this in Swift?:

JS:

```
var user = {name: "Chris Answood"}
user["name"]
```

Comment: to be fair, you wouldn't really ever write that in JS either, unless `"name"` was actually going to be some dynamically chosen string. You'd just write `user.name`, just as in Swift

Comment: I use this a lot in JS. For example I have a var accounts: {chris: 2021, luan: 2020 }; And the user types in the input "chris"; the return for it must be this accounts["value that the user typed in the input"] // return 2021

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That's actually a quite different use case, but it just so happens that JS kind of blurs them together. JS objects are often used in place of dictionaries. They're limited to only have string keys, and you pretty much had no other choice until the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) was introduced in 2014. In Swift, you would model your example with a dictionary, like `let yearsByName = ["chris": 2021, "luan": 2020]`. `yearsByName` would have type `[String: Int]`, which is sugar for `Dictioanry<String, Int>`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have built-in tuple support. You just created an object and get the value of the `name` property inside this object. You have used `user["name"]` but `user.name` would also be possible.

To achieve this in Swift you can create a struct:

```
struct User {
    name: String
}

let user = User(name: "Chris Answood")
print(user.name)
```

Unlike JavaScript, Swift has support for tuples. This is an easy example:

```
let user = (firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Answood")
print(user.firstName)
```

Comment: I'll get from the user is in a String, so I need to access the tuple property with a String, I'm not a beginner in JavaScript, so that's why I asked this question, because I thought I could do something like I do in Js, but then I concluded my doubt , the only way would be with struct is it? By the way thanks, this would solve my doubt. Is this the only way even then?

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up the use cases of structures, dictionaries, classes, etc. The User structure always represents exactly one user. If you want to have multiple users, create an array with multiple user structures. Then you can use `users.first(where: { $0.name == "Chris Answood" })` to search an user from a string.